# How to add checkbox selection for only one choice?

Tags: jquery

I have two kind of questions in survey. One where the user can select multiple choices in each question and then other questions where user has to make only one choice.  I don't want to use radio buttons. I have done this so far but it is not working.

```
<ol class = "single">
   <li> question: question one</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox"> choice one</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox"> choice two</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox"> choice three</li> 
</ol>

<ol class = "multiple">
   <li> question: question two </li>
   <li><input type="checkbox"> choice one </li>
   <li><input type="checkbox"> choice two </li>
   <li><input type="checkbox"> choice three</li> 
</ol>
```

my jQuery code:

```
$('.single').each(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `each`, just narrow the scope of the selector that you are using to bind the click event:

```
$('.single').find('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.single').find('input:checkbox').not($this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: still not able to make it work. It selects all of them.